# resource style/Theme.AppCompat (aka nbgmobilerater.androidapp:style/Theme.AppCompat) not found

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, androidx

I upgraded Xamarin.Android project from android 11 to android 13. I also upgraded the nuget Xamarin.Essentials from version 1.6.1 to version 1.7.5

The errors we receive are the following:

resource style/Theme.AppCompat (aka app_name:style/Theme.AppCompat) not found.
failed linking references.  app_name

Upgraded the nuget Xamarin.Essentials from version 1.6.1 to version 1.7.5
Added the Xamarin.AndroidX libraries
Changed Target Framework and Android Version from 11.0 to 13.0

Comment: Please try to delete bin and obj folders, then restart VS and try again. If the problem persist, please share the code of your `styles.xml`.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>  
  
  <style name="MyBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
  </style>    

  <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
  <style name="SelecteableItemHeader">   
   <item name="android:background">#bbbbbb</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
   <item name="android:paddingLeft">3dp</item>
  </style>
</resources>

Comment: <style name="DrawerMenuItem"><item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall</item>    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall</item>
  </style>
  <style name="DrawerMenuSeparator">
   <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
  </style>

Comment: Sorry,I couldn't reproduce this problem. Could you please share a basic demo to github and share link here so that I can reproduce this problem on my side?

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the Xamarin.Google.Android.Material nuget package?